# How to create an array of objects inside a loop, without a key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am just unable to figure out a way of creating, a list of objects, inside an array, and they should not have any index attached to them.

```js
                        let allConditions = []
                        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            allConditions.push({
                                datasource: 'datasourceName',
                                column_name: 'columnName',
                                id:i
                            })
                        }
                        console.log(allConditions)
```

This gives me a result like:

[image: what i get]

And this is what I need:

[image: what i need]

What am I doing wrong ? The console log I am getting in the snippet is what i want, but that's not what you will get if you copy my code and use it in Google chrome's console. Same goes for my code, I get 2 rows with indexes 0 and 1, which is expected as I am using .push method. What else should I do get an array, which can hold many similar objects, but have no key.

UPDATE: To the people answering that indices will always be there, even if I don't use one, I am sending this data to a backend api, and it rejects my request because it does not find an '**array of objects**. So I am not sure what I should do.

Comment: what you are showing is exactly what you are logging to console. Non-downvoter here. Try: `console.log(...allConditions)`, it will log each individual entry.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but I guess people have no idea what is your use case. I copied your code into Google Chrome's console and I got what you have shown in the screenshot. In order to get exactly what is logged in the snippet, I used `JSON.stringify(allConditions, null, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays will always have indices, although you don't have to use them. Even if you created your array manually outside the loop, it would have indices.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 are equivalent, the keys or array indexes are always there.